# I can't get heroku to interpret my app as a worker

Tags: heroku

First, I'm keep getting the erro code

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

After reading other questions like [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62959849/heroku-java-application-timing-out-after-90-seconds), I realized that I have to let heroku recognize my app as a worker instead of a web.

Then, I put the following line in my profile

`worker: java -jar libs/Maid00-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar`

However, heroku still reconize my app as a web. And the command `heroku ps:scale worker=1 --app maid00` does not work either.

I think there is something wrong with my profile, but I can't figure out how.

[This is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH5Dg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Rename procfile to **Procfile** as per [Heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-naming-and-location)

Comment: I'v watched the documentation before. I aussume I got it correctly since the format is "<process type>: <command>". "worker" is the process and "-jar.." the command. The example "web: java -jar target/myapp-1.0.0.jar" is very similar to my procfile, till it's a web. Sorry for my incompetence but can you tell me exactly how to change my profile? I asked here in the first place because I stil can't get it after I read the documentation

Comment: The filename must start with capital P (ie `Procfile`)

Comment: I'v changed "procfile" to "Procfile", did not work

Comment: Is it in the root folder?

Comment: In the "Resources" tab (https://dashboard.heroku.com/) do you see the Dyno type (worker)?

Comment: No, I can't see the the Dyno type worker. I can only see "web java $JAVA_OPTS -jar IdeaProjects/Maid00/build/libs/Maid00-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar $JAR_OPTS"

Comment: I'v tried to start with the procfile "worker: java -jar C:\Users\Dingda\IdeaProjects\Maid00\build\libs\Maid00-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar" and then peal of the path one by one. Didn't work either. Mabye I got something wrong when I created my procfile. One have to just create a new "File" and then put the line in it right?(I'm using Intellij and you can actually see the entire structure of my project in the original question)

Comment: correct all "\" to "/", the method still does not work